# I am trying to run program in java using hash code but i keep getting the result as illegal start of expression in hash code?

Tags: java, hashcode

I am trying to run the program but keep getting the error of illegal start of expression is also dont know much about hash code. how to use it in proper way and what does this code means?

```
public class Test1 {
 private int num;
 private String data;

 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if (this == obj)
         return true;
     if (obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass())
     return false;
     //objects must be Test at this point
     Test test = (Test) obj;
     return num == test.num &&
         data == test.data || (data != null && data.equals(test.data));
 }

 public int hashCode() {
     int hash = 7;
     hash = 31 * hash + num;
     hash = 31 * hash + (null == data ? 0 : data.hashCode());
     return hash;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see lot of syntax errors in your code, try below class.

```
        public class Test1 {

        private int num;
        private String data;

        public Test1(int num, String data)  {
            this.num = num;
            this.data =data;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if ((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()))
                return false;
            // Objects must be Test at this point.
            Test1 test = (Test1) obj;
            return num == test.num && data == test.data || (data != null && data.equals(test.data));
        }

        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 31 * hash + num;
            hash = 31 * hash + (null == data ? 0 : data.hashCode());
            return hash;
        }


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Test1 obj1 = new Test1(1,"one");
            Test1 obj2 = new Test1(2,"two");

            Test1 obj3 = new Test1(1,"one");
            Test1 obj4 = new Test1(2,"two");

            System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2));
            System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj3));
            System.out.println(obj2.equals(obj3));
            System.out.println(obj2.equals(obj4));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your brackets in the `equals` method look wrong to me...

try

`if(obj==null || (obj.getClass()!=this.getClass()))`

you also need to change the casting to the correct object type

`Test1 test = (Test1)obj;`